# What's so special about binomial coefficients that someone decided to organize them in a triangle?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, soft-question, binomial-coefficients, math-history

I know that binomial coefficients are related to figurate numbers (which were studied by Greeks a loooong time ago, because of its connections to geometry). I also understand **how** the Pascal's triangle works and **why** it is so useful. What I don't understand is what was the 'spark of knowledge' that lead to someone organize it in a triangle, and how this person might have perceived the way to generate new numbers in the triangle.

Comment: By the way, "Pascal's" triangle was known both in China and Persia several centuries before Pascal. Indeed, it was known in Western Europe before Pascal.

Comment: The Pascal's triangle Wikipedia page povides a decent abridged history of its development.

Comment: Guerlando OCs, I nominate you as the next person to sign up for the stackexchange proposal [History of Science and Mathematics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65204/history-of-science-and-mathematics). We are currently in pre beta and trying to collect participants. 5 or 6 questions like this should fulfill your commitment over I think 6 months after the start of beta.

Comment: @J.W.Perry thank you, I'm joining!

Comment: This seems like a question about how the human mind works, rather than math itself.

Comment: I wonder if knowledge of the [Christmas Stocking Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChristmasStockingTheorem.html) came before or after Pascal's triangle became popular. If it came before, it could have been used as an argument for the usefulness of organizing the binomial coeffs. into the triangle.